# Suggestion for probability problem book

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, moment-generating-functions, expected-value, law-of-large-numbers

I am an undergraduate having a course on probability that currently encompasses the topics: General Theory of Expectation, Modes of Convergence (almost surely/conv in probability), Laws of Large numbers, Moment generating function and Characteristics function.
I am seeking for a book that has good exercises/problems in this topic. Please help.
Note: It will be helpful if the exercises do not involve knowledge about measure theory.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the syllabi of major institutes that run an undergraduate probability course? That should give you a good idea. Also, please add the [tag:reference-request] tag to your question.

Comment: Have you tried searching among questions tagged [probability-theory+book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-theory+book-recommendation) and [probability+book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability+book-recommendation)?

Comment: Only just realised that it's an 8 months old post. :/